# Designing database for human resources

Tags: database

So this is overview about HR department database which i have made. Not sure about one part... of this database. I just want to hear feedback for this DB and also dont know how to implement one moment, when employee  decides to resign from job and after sometime ago (2-3 years) we again hire him. i have one idea when we hire employee i make record in table Employee , but when he decides to fire i move this record to other table like DontActiveemployee or i just make point in front of him (IsActive). Also i didnt make table for vacations. So DB looks like this. [image]Sorry about relationship, because this is free DB designer, but i think this is easy to understand.

Comment: An employee has one or more periods of employment. At the very least, each period of employment has a starting date and an ending date. On a separate point, I'm not sure what "contract" means to you, but independent contractors in the USA (where I am) aren't employees.

Comment: Yes employee has more than one period of employment, about starting date and ending date i dont add this fields yet.

Comment: I'm not asking you. I'm telling you. Create a table of employment periods, having *at least* the employee id number and those two date columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easier to just have a job history table with employee id/department id/start/end dates and other columns to keep track of the employee rather than having a separate DontActvieemployee table.